# Backbone.js: Property in Subclassed View is Undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I have several lists of models that I want to display in a web app, so I created a generic class as follows:

```
App.ModelListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.bind('remove', this.removeOne, this);
    },

    addAll: function () {
        this.removeAll();
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    },

    ...

});
```

For each model type, I subclassed `App.ModelListView` like so:

```
App.ProjectListView = App.ModelListView.extend({

    el: $("#project-list"),

    collection: App.Projects,

    listItemView: App.ProjectListItemView

});
```

When I instantiate `App.ProjectListView` view using

```
App.ProjectMainListView = new App.ProjectListView();
```

I'm finding that when it comes time for `App.ModelListView`'s `initialize` function to execute, 'this.collection' is undefined. Why isn't the value for `collection` I defined in the subclass being used? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you're setting App.Projects somewhere after defining your class.  Try changing your creation of the view instance to the following::

```
App.ProjectMainListView = new App.ProjectListView({
    collection: App.Projects
});
```

At the time that you're defining you view, i'll bet you haven't yet set `App.Projects`.

Comment: You're right! I moved my definition of `App.Projects` to before `App.ProjectMainListView` and everything works beautifully. Should have caught that one...